# Controlling the windows 7 on screen keyboard position from code

Tags: windows, windows-7, tablet, docking, on-screen-keyboard

My manager thinks he's seen other people "lock" the windows on screen keyboard to the bottom of their applications, effectively docking it with their window, and wants me to reproduce this. They're using vb6 and occasionally vb.net.

I've done a good amount of googling on the subject and I'm resorting to looking into the windows SDK at the minute, but if someone out there can save me a few days of pain by either confirming that it's not possible or pointing me in the right direction if it is I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that the keyboard locks if I open it from the taskbar icon. It will stay on the bottom of the screen then, even if I'm not on a text field.

No idea how to achieve that programmatically though

Comment: Thanks, that's probably what they've seen. I had a good long look and could find nothing useful, maybe it's buried somewhere deep in the windows api.